# Error: Program type already present: com.google.ads.AdRequest$ErrorCode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, implementation

So I updated my `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'`to the latest one which is 17.1.1 and the error am receiving is "Error: Program type already present: com.google.ads.AdRequest$ErrorCode"

Here is my gradle codes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.neurondigital.wallpaperapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'


implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.1'
implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.1.0"
implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

implementation project(':BigImageViewer')
implementation project(':GlideImageLoader')


implementation 'com.github.frank-zhu:pullzoomview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.1'


implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
}

implementation 'com.neurondigital.ratebolt:ratebolt:0.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can somebody please help me this error is quite frustrating and am just a beginner dev please lend me your expertise some one.

Comment: do u have  ```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'``` in build.gradle?please upgrade it to this version

Comment: okay thank you sir will try it